# Turn public list to set with returning unique values

Tags: class, list, set, public, getter

I have below declaration for a public list which I need to make a set so that only unique values show up. If not Set atleast I need this list to return unique values. Can someone please help me?

**Apex class:**

```
public list<Compliance_incident_abv__c > getRepList(){
    return [select id,Rep_abv__r.name from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25];
}
```

Comment: Your query includes the `Id` of the `Compliance_incident_abv__c` records so adding the query result to a set will not reduce the values returned as each record will have a different `Id`. Suggest you clarify your requirement...

Comment: Yes Keith. This is the current set.                                                                                   public Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c> getRepList(){ return new Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c>([select Representative_Name_abv__c from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25]); }

Comment: You should never use `Set<SObject>`. There are very rare exceptions to this rule, but this is not one of them. A query never returns the same record twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using the following code:

```
Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c> s = new Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c>(yourList);
```

Here you can find an excerpt from the [APEX documentation for the Set Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm):

> **Set(listToCopy)**
>
> Creates a new instance of the Set class by coping the list elements. T is the data type of the elements in the set and list and can be any data type.
>
> **Signature**
>
> `public Set<T>(List<T> listToCopy)`

So for example you could update your code to this:

```
public Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c> getRepList(){
    return new Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c>([select id,Rep_abv__r.name from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25]);
}
```

Comment: But this list was a get list that I was retrieving in page. Do you mean I need to declare this set just below getRepList() declaration in my apex class?

Comment: What should I use instead of this? public list<Compliance_incident_abv__c > getRepList(){
    return [select id,Rep_abv__r.name from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25];
}

Comment: I just updated my answer, so the posted code can be formatted.

Comment: Thanks Markus! Here the set can't assign the relational field. Error: Unknown property 'SetValue.Rep_abv__r' I am working on it, will fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! ;) Oh, I didn't check your query until now: This seems to be because you select a value from another related object. So this isn't a field of type Compliance_incident_abv__c. Maybe you need to select another type (e.g. using a custom class for this purpose) for your set, so you can store the desired fields.

Comment: I have created a formula field to populate the value in Compliance_Incident_abv__c but still the error shows. Error: Unknown property 'SetValue.Representative_Name_abv__c'. Can you please suggest me what change I need?

Comment: This is what I am using now.                                                                                          public Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c> getRepList(){
    return new Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c>([select Representative_Name_abv__c from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25]);
}

Comment: I managed to bypass the error. Now the problem is Set values are IDs only and not the desired field values. :)

Comment: I am creating a separate question for that. Please help if you get some time.

Comment: Please find the question here.                                                              http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154244/apex-repeat-shows-ids-instead-of-field-values