# Apex repeat shows Ids instead of field values

Tags: visualforce, controller, list, repeat, set

I have below set in my controller where I am populating a formula text field values in a set of Compliance_Incident_abv__c. Unfortunately, in page it shows only the Ids and not the Representative_name_abv__c field values.

**Apex controller - Set**

```
public Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c > getRepList(){
    return new Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c >([select Representative_Name_abv__c from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25]);
}
```

**Apex Page - Repeat**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!RepList}" var="RList">            
      apexRepList.push('{!RList}');            
  </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: how are you iterating in vf page.

Comment: If you try that : `apexRepList.push('{!RList.Representative_Name_abv__c}');` ?

Comment: Yes when I do that the page simply not getting compiled and throws this error.  Error: Unknown property 'SetValue.Representative_Name_abv__c'

Comment: Change the `Set<Compliance_incident_abv__c>` to `List<Compliance_incident_abv__c>`

Comment: That I can't as I need unique values. :(. Initially it was List only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your two records have same value then the Set will not help you and you will get duplicates. So you can do something like

```
public Set<string> getRepList(){
    Set<String> strSet = new Set<String>();
    for(Compliance_incident_abv__c ab: [select Representative_Name_abv__c from Compliance_incident_abv__c where Rep_abv__c!=null limit 25])
        strSet.add(ab.Representative_Name_abv__c );
    return strSet;
}
```

You don't need to change anything on Visualforce side.